# Set a launcher without leaving the current activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

When my homescreen is cleared from defaults, I can send out this intent to trigger the "launcher chooser dialog", where I can select which launcher to be default.

```
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

The problem is, when the user has chosen a launcher, my current activity is brought back and the new launcher comes up in foreground.

I've tried to launch the intent as a chooser by:

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose one"));
```

but that wouldn't work.

Is there a way to keep my current activity visible while setting a new launcher?

Comment: I believe this is possible, but I don't know how. Nova Launcher achieves this exact thing. When you press "Select Default Home" in its menu, Nova goes to the "back/visible" state while the user selects the default launcher.

Comment: @KickAss Yes i belive so, i've seen it in other apps too!

Comment: One second, I'm taking a look at Nova launcher's source code (shhh!)

Comment: See answer below. I've edited it

Answer (score 1):

Okay, Nova Launcher uses this (I think). This is their **HomeReset** class.

```
public class HomeReset
  extends Activity
{
  public static ComponentName D(PackageManager paramPackageManager)
  {
    ComponentName localComponentName = null;
    try
    {
      Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN", null);
      localIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
      localIntent.addFlags(270532608);
      localComponentName = localIntent.resolveActivity(paramPackageManager);
      if (("android".equals(localComponentName.getPackageName())) && ("com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity".equals(localComponentName.getClassName()))) {
        return null;
      }
      return localComponentName;
    }
    catch (Exception localException)
    {
      Log.e("HomeReseter", "Exception when trying to find default home", localException);
    }
    return localComponentName;
  }

  public static Intent D()
  {
    Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN", null);
    localIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
    localIntent.addFlags(270532608);
    return localIntent;
  }

  public static void D(Activity paramActivity)
  {
    PackageManager localPackageManager = paramActivity.getPackageManager();
    localPackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(paramActivity.getPackageName(), "com.teslacoilsw.launcher.homereset.HomeReset"), 1, 1);
    Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN", null);
    localIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
    localIntent.addFlags(270532608);
    localIntent.addFlags(268435456);
    localIntent.putExtra("homereset_return_to_settings", true);
    paramActivity.startActivity(localIntent);
    localPackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(paramActivity.getPackageName(), "com.teslacoilsw.launcher.homereset.HomeReset"), 2, 1);
    paramActivity.startActivity(localIntent);
  }

  public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
  {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    Context localContext = getApplicationContext();
    PackageManager localPackageManager = getPackageManager();
    localPackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(localContext.getPackageName(), "com.teslacoilsw.launcher.homereset.HomeReset"), 1, 1);
    Intent localIntent1 = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN", null);
    localIntent1.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
    localIntent1.addFlags(270532608);
    localIntent1.setFlags(268435456);
    localContext.startActivity(localIntent1);
    localPackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(localContext.getPackageName(), "com.teslacoilsw.launcher.homereset.HomeReset"), 2, 1);
    Intent localIntent2 = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN", null);
    localIntent2.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
    localIntent2.addFlags(270532608);
    localIntent2.setFlags(402653184);
    localContext.startActivity(localIntent2);
  }
}
```

Does that help? I can't find its R.Java file cause it's obfuscated so I can't tell you the ID references.

**EDIT:** I think this is how the above activity is launched. This is from their **SettingsActivity**:

```
...
      Preference localPreference = findPreference("select_home");
      if (localPreference == null) {
        return;
      }
      Object localObject = null;
      PackageManager localPackageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
      ComponentName localComponentName = HomeReset.D(localPackageManager);
      if (localComponentName != null) {}
      try
      {
        localObject = localPackageManager.getActivityInfo(localComponentName, 0).loadLabel(localPackageManager);
      }
      catch
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your info! It's quite hard to get a grip of it though:/
Every time they do addFlags(), the scrambled number inbetween, is that a consant? like Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK?

Comment: Yeah, it's the references you'd find in the R.java file. But I can't find the file in the project because it's scrambled. Unfortunately, I  am a beginner and this is the most I can help you here. Maybe there is a way to convert those Constant/id references to actual words. Search for it :)

Comment: Hello, @Sebastian Have you found what is Constant Name for flag  402653184?